# Jenkins: is it possible to expand the Pipeline script Definition window?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to expand the Jenkins Pipeline script Definition window?

At the moment, I have a huge external monitor and, in the centre of it, about the size of a matchbox, is my Pipeline script editor.

Seems crazy but can't expand it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible....What you can do is copy the pipleine script into a notepad(notepad++) and then do the changes and paste it back here...That's what i do.